# Migrating a theme from OpenCart To Wordpress(WooCommerce)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opencart

I have a website using OpenCart whose theme was designed by someone else, somehow manually by editing php file. I have to convert that site to woocommerce application. May I know which directory is to be copied ? Is this migration possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify which one, all the site or just the Theme, because a migrating from a different platform is really complex.

I don't have a lot of experience in Woocommerce but I don't think is possible with just copying and pasting.

A theme is a very complex group of files (HTML, PHP, JS/jQuery) and is developed with a very specific environment in mind. Which will cause to your theme not working at all.
I think the options you have is buying a theme or use a free theme ([StoreFront Theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/storefront/)) and customize it. Well, also is the option of hiring a developer for that.

> May I know which directory is to be copied?

I don't know about OpenCart, but for Woocommerce you can add themes from your Admin Panel

```
WP-ADMIN->>Appearance->>Themes
```

or via FTP in the directory of your Wordpresss Setup.

```
/wp-content/themes
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very different platforms. Never can be simply copied any theme from opencart to woocomerce or vice versa. You can import/export database data with some additional extensions only... Of course developers can create very similar themes to this different platforms, but not simple copy.